# Unable to edit values in a DataGridView (using BindingList)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, datagridview, properties

It seems that, due to an unknown cause, I am now unable to edit anything in my DataGridView. The DGV's ReadOnly property value is false, and all columns except for one all have the ReadOnly property set to false as well.

I'm beginning to think that it may be due to a special value I tried adding to one of my classes, one that I only wanted to be modified within the class, but still read only to the public. I don't think that value is messing with anything else, but none the less, here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
        private void loaderWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        if (e.UserState != null)
        {
            savefiles.Add((SaveFile)e.UserState);
        }
    }
```

Where savefiles is a BindingList, and where SaveFile is my class:

```
public class SaveFile
{
    private string d_directory;
    private int d_weirdnumber;
    private bool d_isautosave;
    private string d_fullname;
    private string d_datatype;
    private string d_owner;
    private bool d_isquicksave;
    private string d_title;
    private string d_gametime;

    public SaveFile() { }

    public SaveFile(string directory, int weirdnumber, bool isautosave, string fullname, string datatype, string owner, bool isquicksave, string title)
    {
        d_directory = directory;
        d_weirdnumber = weirdnumber;
        d_isautosave = isautosave;
        d_fullname = fullname;
        d_datatype = datatype;
        d_owner = owner;
        d_isquicksave = isquicksave;
        d_title = title;
    }

    public string Gametime
    {
        get { return d_gametime; }
    }

    public string Datatype
    {
        get { return d_datatype; }
        set { d_datatype = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return d_title; }
        set { d_title = value; }
    }

    public bool IsQuickSave
    {
        get { return d_isquicksave; }
        set { d_isquicksave = value; }
    }

    public bool IsAutoSave
    {
        get { return d_isautosave; }
        set { d_isautosave = value; }
    }

    public string Directory
    {
        get { return d_directory; }
        set { d_directory = value; }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return d_fullname; }
        set
        {
            d_fullname = value;
            string[] split = value.Split(new char[]{'-'});
            foreach (string str in split)
            {
                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(str, "^\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d$"))
                {
                    d_gametime = str;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int Weirdnumber
    {
        get { return d_weirdnumber; }
        set { d_weirdnumber = value; }
    }

    public string Owner
    {
        get { return d_owner; }
        set { d_owner = value; }
    }
}
```

Gametime is that special property I mentioned earlier. It doesn't have a set function, but according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), I should be in the clear, right?

Can anyone then tell me why I may not be able to edit any of the DGV cells?

**EDIT:** I just found out that *not* setting AutoGenerateColumns to false allows me to edit again, but I still don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours, a friend finally took a look at it over Remote Desktop. He wrote a function to force all columns to have a non read-only status, and go figure, it worked. So we looked at the column properties in the editor, and somehow... I don't know why... they were all set to Read only. I swear I checked them 4 times before.

The lesson of this story (I guess): When in doubt, check your settings. When not in doubt, become doubtful. Otherwise, file a bug report to Microsoft :\

Comment: I've just experienced the same problem.  Lesson leaned: don't trust VS Designer (VS2012)